# Processing a SOAP request

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, windows-services

I have created a windows service for processing XML file that takes a file from a file folder ( it is polling the XML file from that file folder continuously). When i will drop the XML file inside the file folder, my service will pick the file and start processing it.After processing, it sends the file to the destination location. So currently i am dealing with the file folder only.

Now my idea is to poll SOAP messages from WCF service using my windows service just like what i am currently doing with the help of file folder. After processing, the response should also be sent to the WCF service. How can i implement my idea ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution would be to create a continuous loop within your code that calls the web service.

You can then make the code pause for an amount of time before performing the loop again. The pause can be accomplished with [Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)